# Angular app using firebase getting $add is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angular-services

I have an angular service:

```
(function(){
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module('todoapp')
        .factory('ListService', ListService);
    ListService.$inject = ['$firebaseArray'];

    function ListService($firebaseArray) {
        var ref = new Firebase('https://---firebase-name---.firebaseio.com/items/'),
        list = $firebaseArray(ref);

        return list;


    }

})();
```

That gets called from a controller

```
(function () {
"use strict";

angular
    .module('todoapp')
    .controller('ListController', ListController);

ListController.$inject = ['$scope', '$log', 'ListService'];

/* @ngInject */
function ListController($scope, $log, ListService) {

    var listCtrl = this;

    listCtrl.items = ListService;

    listCtrl.add = function(form){

        //ADD TO FIREBASE
        console.log(listCtrl.newList);
        listCtrl.newList.$add(listCtrl.newList);
}
```

and when I trigger `listCtrl.add()` I get the error:

```
listCtrl.newList.$add is not a function
```

Now the `listCtrl.newList` object I am trying to pass includes only nodes that are included in the firebase object I am trying to update but not all of them, thought I only need to include the nodes that are changing. I do not think that the object is the problem cause the method `$add` is where it is erroring out and not inside it.

I have also tried adding $asArray to the firebase meothod like so:

```
list = $firebaseArray(ref).$asArray();
```

But that errors out not finding `$asArray`
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`listCtrl.items.$add` instead of `listCtrl.newList.$add`

Comment: Thank you for the extra set of eyes.